# Why do I have bunch of 'NULL's in the resulting 'join'...why is that?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

Trying to join an Excel-table(.xls) - cleaned up - with a polygon shapefile. Getting a bunch of 'NULL' why this ?

[image: Trying to join an Excel-table(.xls) - cleaned up - with a polygon shapefile. Getting a bunch of 'NULL' why this ?]

But validating the two aboove mentioned files go's without any error, all green ! Strange...

[image: But validating the two aboove mentioned files go's without any error, all green ! Strange...]

Comment: the 2nd layer/table doesn't have the same key. You are joining on text, so beware of spaces or other hidden characters.

Answer (score 1):

A successful join validation does **not** mean you got a 1:1 join.
Your linked image of the join validation shows that 1 of 99 was successful.

I see what looks like 1 joined record in the other image.

I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: Does it mean that i can work with the joined file and use it for making some maps even if it's showing up a bunch of 'NULL's ?

Comment: Certainly. But if you are mapping a variable in the joined table, you will only get two classes: NULL, and whatever is in that one joined record.  It sounds like you expected a higher match rate in your join,  though. So you should probably investigate why  so many failed  -maybe there are extra spaces in your join field in one the tables that are not in the other table or something?

Comment: I never have good luck working with Excel tables. Maybe convert yout table to  a .dbf or a .gdb table with the "Excel to Table" tool

Comment: There is only ONE variable that is joined: Called KOMNAVN(municipality name) from the municipality layer with the corresponding Excel-file(municipality name).